# Estrutura de um JSON encadeado

Tags: javascript, json

Estava elaborando uma aplicação web, onde eu precisei usar JSON, tive alguns problemas, mas consegui. Agora preciso deixar tudo na página da aplicação dinâmico, então tudo tem que ser passado pelo JSON, porém nunca fiz um JSON com vários encadeamentos, então não sei se está correto a forma que eu fiz e também não sei se há alguma difrença na hora de pegar com o JS.

Segue o JSON que estou criando para testar:

```
{
    "cidade1":[{
                "txtheader":{"Lorem Ipsum dolor"},
                "chart1":[{"valor1":30,"valor2":350}],
                "chart2":[{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460}],
                "chart3":[{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540}],
                "tabela":[
                            {"Fornecedor": "fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12/09/2015","Passageiro": "Pedro","Confirmação":"Não","Localizador":"Sim",
                            "LocalizadorGds":"Não","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao": "Ativo","Identificador": "Não"}
                        ]
               }],
    "cidade2":[{
                "txtheader":{"Lorem Ipsum dolor"},
                "chart1":[{"valor1":30,"valor2":350}],
                "chart2":[{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460}],
                "chart3":[{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540}],
                "tabela":[
                            {"Fornecedor": "fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12/09/2015","Passageiro": "Pedro","Confirmação":"Não","Localizador":"Sim",
                            "LocalizadorGds":"Não","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao": "Ativo","Identificador": "Não"}
                        ]
               }]
}
```

Ai entraria várias cidades diferentes, no caso eu só coloquei duas, porem elas vão ter a mesma estrutura.

Exemplo ilustrado:

Todos os dados dessa página precisa vir do JSON, até o texto que eu chamei de txtheader e os dados para os gráficos.

[image: 11]

Nessa imagem abaixo, mostra o `<option>` que também será dinâmico e quando selecionado ele carrega o json e carrega os dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a tabela que está linkada ao gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cada cidade vai ter mais objetos dentro dessa array com o seu próprio `txtheader` etc? Dá-me ideia que tens arrays com somente 1 objeto dentro onde bastaria ter apenas o objeto... Ou seja, por exemplo diretamente `"cidade1":{` sem usar `[` para ser uma array.

Comment: @Sergio Não sei se entendi, mas cada cidade vão ter 5 "variáveis", (txtheader/chart1/chart2/chart3/tabela), me confundo um pouco com o uso do {} e do [], mas a minha ideia é que o txtheader não fosse um array, e que os outros 4 fossem. Para eu conseguir preencher alguns gráficos com os valores dos charts e descarregar a "tabela", em uma tabela.

Comment: @Sergio Acredito que eu estou te confundindo por alguma sintaxe errada no JSON. Como estou criando esse JSON na mão para poder testar, acredito que tenha me atrapalhado com alguma coisa.

Comment: cara é mais fácil você montar a estrutura em array no php, e depois usar o `json_encode()`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Teria como você me mostrar um exemplo? Eu poderia colocar direto na declaração da variável o json e usar o json_encode(). Mas to com mais duvida na parte da estrutura mesmo, como vai ficar esses arrays um dentro do outro.

Comment: Olha na resposta.

Comment: @GiovanniBernini o teu JSON está correto se cada cidade tiver vários objetos dentro. Senão deves tirar essas arrays. Daí a minha pergunta. Se explicares a estrutura dos dados que queres montar podemos ajudar-te a criar o JSON. Em vez de estarmos a ver o JSON que tens e sem saber bem onde queres chegar.

Comment: @IvanFerrer pois, ele próprio admitiu que não está confiante em JSON. Seria interessante saber a estrutura dos dados para o podermos ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio Vou editar meu post com uma explicação sobre a estrutura, vou ilustrar para passar melhor a minha mensagem.

Comment: @Sergio Editado. Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenha sempre em mente que a representação de informações JSON obedece a seguinte regra: para cada valor, atribui-se um nome (ou rótulo) que descreve o seu significado.

Exemplo:

```
"nome" : "José"
```

Por exemplo: Se eu precisasse de mais informações sobre José, tipo idade (inteiro) e se ele tem carteira de habilitação (booleano), as informações ficariam desse jeito:

```
"nome": "José",
"idade" : 52,
"habilitado": true
```

Está vendo como funciona? Desse modo, a partir desses tipos básicos, é possivel construir tipos mais complexos, como **arrays** e **objetos**.

Os arrays são delimitados por colchetes, com seus elementos separados entre vírgulas.

Exemplo:

```
["Maria", "João", "Joaquim"]
```

Os objetos são delimitados por chaves e podem ser compostos por múltiplos pares nome/valor, bem como arrays e outros objetos.

Exemplo:

```
    {
        "nome": "José",
        "idade": 52,
        "habilitado": true,
        "filhos": [
            "Maria",
            "João",
            "Joaquim"
        ]
    }
```

Desse modo, pode-se criar um array de objetos.

Exemplo:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "José",
        "idade": 52,
        "habilitado": true,
        "filhos": [
            "Maria",
            "João",
            "Joaquim"
        ]
    },
    {
        "nome": "Sebastião",
        "idade": 50,
        "habilitado": false,
        "filhos": [
            "Pedro"
        ]
    }
]
```

Para validar o seu JSON, você pode usar este site: http://jsonlint.com/

Referências: http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-formato-json/25275

Comment: Mais uma vez não concordo com a afirmação acima. O json está errado.

Comment: @Nikofoxxxx, testei os dois exemplos e ambos estão retornando com erro.

Comment: Olá @IvanFerrer, me perdoe pelo primeiro exemplo, realmente foi falha minha. Porém o segundo JSON está válido. Já editei a resposta.

Comment: Sim, é verdade. O segundo eu testei e deu certo. eu que esqueci de copiar a última chave.

Comment: Tranquilo! Obrigado por notar o erro!

Comment: Você sabe porque o primeiro exemplo deu erro?

Comment: Na verdade foi porque eu não tinha colocado os objetos de exemplo dentro de um delimitador, separando-os por vírgula.

Comment: Agora está correto.

Comment: Dei +1 pela correção

Comment: Obrigado por tudo! :D

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você faça a estrutura em array, e depois converta para json:

```
$array_data = array(
'cidade1'=>array(
                 'textheader'=>'Lorem Ipsum dolor',
                 'chart1'=>array('valor1'=>30, 'valor2'=>350),
                 'chart2'=>array('valor1'=>500,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>170, 'valor4'=>460),
                 'chart3'=>array('valor1'=>1000,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>1170, 'valor4'=>1460,'valor5'=>660,'valor6'=>1120,'valor7'=>1030,'valor8'=>540),
                 'tabela'=>array("Fornecedor"=>"fff","Trecho"=>"ttt","Data"=>"12/09/2015","Passageiro"=> "Pedro","Confirmação"=>"Não","Localizador"=>"Sim",
                            "LocalizadorGds"=>"Não","Numero da solicitacao"=>1002,"Status da Integracao"=>"Ativo","Identificador"=>"Não")
           ),
'cidade2'=>array(
                 'textheader'=>'Lorem Ipsum dolor',
                 'chart1'=>array('valor1'=>30, 'valor2'=>350),
                 'chart2'=>array('valor1'=>500,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>170, 'valor4'=>460),
                 'chart3'=>array('valor1'=>1000,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>1170, 'valor4'=>1460,'valor5'=>660,'valor6'=>1120,'valor7'=>1030,'valor8'=>540),
                 'tabela'=>array("Fornecedor"=>"fff","Trecho"=>"ttt","Data"=>"12/09/2015","Passageiro"=> "Pedro","Confirmação"=>"Não","Localizador"=>"Sim",
                            "LocalizadorGds"=>"Não","Numero da solicitacao"=>1002,"Status da Integracao"=>"Ativo","Identificador"=>"Não")
           )
);
echo json_encode($array_data);
```

Se estiver usando PHP 4.5 ou superior:

```
 $array_data = [
    'cidade1'=> [
                     'textheader'=>'Lorem Ipsum dolor',
                     'chart1'=> ['valor1'=>30, 'valor2'=>350],
                     'chart2'=> ['valor1'=>500,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>170, 'valor4'=>460],
                     'chart3'=> ['valor1'=>1000,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>1170, 'valor4'=>1460,'valor5'=>660,'valor6'=>1120,'valor7'=>1030,'valor8'=>540],
                     'tabela'=> ["Fornecedor"=>"fff","Trecho"=>"ttt","Data"=>"12/09/2015","Passageiro"=> "Pedro","Confirmação"=>"Não","Localizador"=>"Sim",
                                "LocalizadorGds"=>"Não","Numero da solicitacao"=>1002,"Status da Integracao"=>"Ativo","Identificador"=>"Não"]
               ],
    'cidade2'=> [
                     'textheader'=>'Lorem Ipsum dolor',
                     'chart1'=> ['valor1'=>30, 'valor2'=>350],
                     'chart2'=> ['valor1'=>500,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>170, 'valor4'=>460],
                     'chart3'=> ['valor1'=>1000,'valor2'=>400,'valor3'=>1170, 'valor4'=>1460,'valor5'=>660,'valor6'=>1120,'valor7'=>1030,'valor8'=>540],
                     'tabela'=> ["Fornecedor"=>"fff","Trecho"=>"ttt","Data"=>"12/09/2015","Passageiro"=> "Pedro","Confirmação"=>"Não","Localizador"=>"Sim",
                                "LocalizadorGds"=>"Não","Numero da solicitacao"=>1002,"Status da Integracao"=>"Ativo","Identificador"=>"Não"]
               ]
    ];
 echo json_encode($array_data);
```

Convertido seria isso:

```
  {
   "cidade1":
       {
        "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
        "chart1":{"valor1":30,"valor2":350},
        "chart2":{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460},
        "chart3":{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540},
        "tabela":{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12\/09\/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirma\u00e7\u00e3o":"N\u00e3o","Localizador":"Sim","LocalizadorGds":"N\u00e3o","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"N\u00e3o"}
        },
   "cidade2":
       {
       "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
        "chart1":{"valor1":30,"valor2":350},
        "chart2":{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460},
        "chart3":{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540},
        "tabela":{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12\/09\/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirma\u00e7\u00e3o":"N\u00e3o","Localizador":"Sim","LocalizadorGds":"N\u00e3o","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"N\u00e3o"}
       }
  }
```

Agora vamos supor que você queira pegar o status da solicitação da primeira tabela apenas através do javascript.

Execute isso no seu console:

```
var col =  {
       "cidade1":
           {
            "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
            "chart1":{"valor1":30,"valor2":350},
            "chart2":{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460},
            "chart3":{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540},
            "tabela":{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12\/09\/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirma\u00e7\u00e3o":"N\u00e3o","Localizador":"Sim","LocalizadorGds":"N\u00e3o","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"N\u00e3o"}
            },
       "cidade2":
           {
           "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
            "chart1":{"valor1":30,"valor2":350},
            "chart2":{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170,"valor4":460},
            "chart3":{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170,"valor4":1460,"valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540},
            "tabela":{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12\/09\/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirma\u00e7\u00e3o":"N\u00e3o","Localizador":"Sim","LocalizadorGds":"N\u00e3o","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"N\u00e3o"}
           }
      };

console.log(col.cidade1.tabela['Numero da solicitacao']);
```

Aqui um exemplo de uso com array:

```
var seu_json = {
                "cidade1":
                    [{
                      "id":1,
                      "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
                      "chart1":[{"valor1":30,"valor2":350 }],
                      "chart2":[{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170, "valor4":460 }],
                      "chart3":[{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170, "valor4":1460, "valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540 }],
                      "tabela":[{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12/09/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirmação":"Não","Localizador":"Sim",
                                "LocalizadorGds":"Não","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"Não"}]
                    }],
            "cidade2":
                    [{
                      "id":2,
                      "textheader":"Lorem Ipsum dolor",
                      "chart1":[{"valor1":30,"valor2":350 }],
                      "chart2":[{"valor1":500,"valor2":400,"valor3":170, "valor4":460 }],
                      "chart3":[{"valor1":1000,"valor2":400,"valor3":1170, "valor4":1460, "valor5":660,"valor6":1120,"valor7":1030,"valor8":540 }],
                      "tabela":[{"Fornecedor":"fff","Trecho":"ttt","Data":"12/09/2015","Passageiro":"Pedro","Confirmação":"Não","Localizador":"Sim",
                                "LocalizadorGds":"Não","Numero da solicitacao":1002,"Status da Integracao":"Ativo","Identificador":"Não"}]
                    }]
           };
console.log(seu_json);
```

Comment: Entendi, mas o Ivan, essa 'tabela' terá mais dados, para realmente preencher uma tabela, como eu faria ela? se fosse só uma tabela no json eu faria [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Pedro",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Val",
    }] 
por exemplo, mas dentro da 'tabela' eu já não sei como estruturar isso.

Comment: Acredito que eu tenha conseguido, coloquei assim: "tabela": [ { "Fornecedor": "fff"}]  com o [, validei no JSONLint e deu certo, vou acabar de escrever e vou testar, valeu!